# PHP/JavaScript Redirect Issue

Tags: javascript, php

As a side project I have attempted to create a COVID-19 Self Assessment tool. Everything has worked up until now. When I post all of the form data into the PHP script, and use this method, but I keep getting an error that I cannot modify the headers.

```
    $name = $symtpoms = $home = $travel = $contact = $doctorOrdered = $appExposed = null;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $name = input($_POST["name"]);
        $symtpoms = input($_POST["symptoms"]);
        $home = input($_POST["home"]);
        $travel = input($_POST["travel"]);
        $contact = input($_POST["contact"]);
        $doctorOrdered = input($_POST["doctorOrdered"]);
        $appExposed = input($_POST["appExposed"]);

        if (isset($symtpoms) && isset($home) && isset($travel) && isset($contact) && isset($doctorOrdered) && isset($appExposed)) {
            if ($symtpoms == true || $home == true || $travel == true || $contact == true || $doctorOrdered == true || $appExposed == true) {
                Header("Location: #safeFalse");
            } else {
                Header("Location: #safeTrue");
            }
        }
    }

    function input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
```

Then, when I try the code below, no matter what outcome I should arrive at, I always get sent to #safeFalse

```
    $name = $symtpoms = $home = $travel = $contact = $doctorOrdered = $appExposed = null;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $name = input($_POST["name"]);
        $symtpoms = input($_POST["symptoms"]);
        $home = input($_POST["home"]);
        $travel = input($_POST["travel"]);
        $contact = input($_POST["contact"]);
        $doctorOrdered = input($_POST["doctorOrdered"]);
        $appExposed = input($_POST["appExposed"]);

        if (isset($symtpoms) && isset($home) && isset($travel) && isset($contact) && isset($doctorOrdered) && isset($appExposed)) {
            if ($symtpoms == true || $home == true || $travel == true || $contact == true || $doctorOrdered == true || $appExposed == true) {
                echo "<script type='text/JavaScript'>
                window.location.href = '#safeFalse';
                </script>";
            } else {
                echo "<script type='text/JavaScript'>
                window.location.href = '#safeTrue';
                </script>";
            }
        }
    }

    function input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
```

Greatly appreciate all help. Thanks

Comment: `I keep getting an error that I cannot modify the headers.`...so fix it then. Googling the error message would give you lots of insight into it. Somewhere (probably earlier on in your script than the code you've shown) something is being output before you set the header. That isn't allowed. If you're intending to redirect, then output is pointless anyway, so just go and prevent it from happening

Comment: I've moved past the Headers problem, but why does it keep redirecting to the same place no matter the outcome??

Comment: Well, did you debug it? I've no idea what values are actually being submitted in your $_POST. Do a `var_dump($_POST);` and find out. This kind of basic check should be your first debugging step. Those values are fed into your `if` statment logic, which basically says "if any one of the values is true, redirect to the "false" page". You also didn't say what you expect to happen given any particular set of data, so I can't judge whether you've written the logic correctly (per your requirements) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***For the first problem:***

This arises when you have output something prior to setting the header. Somewhere in your script (a part you haven't shown here), you are outputting something. Remove all the output and the error will disappear.

an example of this could be:

```
echo "output!";
header("Location: file.php"); //WE FAIL... WE OUTPUTTED SOMETHING IN THE LINE ABOVE
```

***for the second problem:***

Well, taking a look at the following statement:

```
 if (isset($symtpoms) && isset($home) && isset($travel) && isset($contact) && isset($doctorOrdered) && isset($appExposed))
```

it basically says: if all of these are set (set and not NULL), go on.

You then say:

```
if ($symtpoms == true || $home == true || $travel == true || $contact == true || $doctorOrdered == true || $appExposed == true)
```

Notice how you use 2 `=` signs? This means that it evaluates truthy and falsy. If ANY of these variables evaluate to `true`, which is the case, considering I highly doubt all of the variables are given falsy values, it'll ALWAYS go into the if statement.

You basically say: If a OR b OR c OR e etc. evaluates to true, it should proceed.

The only way this would fail would be if ALL the variables evaluate to a falsy value, which again, I highly doubt, because that would mean all the variables would have to be either `0`, `null` or `""`, in which we can basically nullify the `null` value, since that has already been handled by the `isset`.

Comment: thank you very much. I did something to fix the headers problem, but I cannot remember what as it was a few hours ago. In regards to the always going to false, you solved it. I had been pondering between using 2 different data types and apparently forgot to fully switch to the current one. thank you for the in depth response.

Comment: @EducatedMilk if it resolved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer for future readers. Good luck on your programming adventures!